# need help to understand complex javascript reg exp

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to understand the meaning of this regexp:

`/^\s*[^#].*?\s*:\s*([a-f0-9.:]+?)\s*-\s*([a-f0-9.:]+?)\s*$/`

I am trying to understand a nodejs's module and since I am not expert on regular expression, it is a little difficult to do.

If someone could translate that expression, it would be very helpful.

---

nice answers.

what I'm trying to understand is the following function:

```
var parseBlocklist = function(filename) {

 var blocklistData = fs.readFileSync(filename, { encoding: 'utf8' });
 var blocklist = [];
 blocklistData.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
 var match = null;
 if ((match = /^\s*[^#].*?\s*:\s*([a-f0-9.:]+?)\s*-\s*([a-f0-9.:]+?)\s*$/.exec(line))) {
  blocklist.push({
  start: match[1],
  end: match[2]
 });
}
});
return blocklist;
};
```

For the moment I realized that:

The function takes a file as a parameter and reads the entire contents

After that, for each row of content that makes up the file does something using the regular expression.

it seems that the results of this "something" is pushed into the array.

If you can, please explain better the purpose of this function.

Comment: [Debuggex will allow you to see a visual representation of your regex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/9r5nMnSj35tNF7IR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given regex is a combination of multiple regex, keep in mind that you can break this complex regex into multiple smaller one, and each smaller one can be easily translated

Refer to this wiki page for finding the meaning of each small regex parts
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Your regex can be broken into

```
/^                         Start of line
\s*                        zero or more space non white character
[^#].?                     not equal to hash atleast one
\s                         non white character
:                          colon
\s*                        zero or more space non white character
([a-f0-9.:]+?)             hexa digit (one or more)
\s*                        zero or more space non white character    
-                          dash
\s*                        zero or more space non white character
([a-f0-9.:]+?)             hexa digit (one or more) 
\s*                        zero or more space non white character
$/                         end of line
```

Answer (score 0):

/^ beginning of line

\s* optional whitespace

[^#] anything except a #

.*? a load of anything

\s* more whitespace

: a colon

\s* more whitespace

([a-f0-9.:]+?) some hex but allowing . and : for some reason

\s* more whitespace

- minus

\s* more whitespace

([a-f0-9.:]+?) more hex

\s* more whitespace

$/ end of line